# How to get VScode to recognize history and document in react js apps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

VScode is highlighting lines that use `document` and `history` as undefined per my linter rules.

How to get these to be recognized as valid?
Currently I am disabling no-undef (at the line level) but that is obviously a hack.

Comment: Have you set the `browser` [environment](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `globals` directive](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) to specify variables which are defined globally.

However, you shouldn't need to access `document` or `history` directly in a React app in the first place.

Generally you should interact with the `history` only through the use of a [router](https://reactrouter.com/), and you should avoid direct DOM access entirely.

The main things you want want to use direct DOM access for are changing things in the `<head>` which are better handled with [React Helmet](https://css-tricks.com/its-all-in-the-head-managing-the-document-head-of-a-react-powered-site-with-react-helmet/) or for manipulating content of a component which should almost always be done through state and props and where the rare exceptions should be handled via [a `useRef` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) instead of searching the document via `document.querySelector` or similar.

Comment: using localStorage also btw